# Sending same text to many people, nobody sees other recipients

Tags: iphone, messages, text, client

I'm trying to organize a club/business and would like to send the same text to my clientele.

I do not want individual recipients to see who else is a recipient, as most clients don't know each other. This implies I also don't want recipients to see other recipients's replies and that they would ideally go to me. Not being able to reply at all is not a deal breaker.

If such a feature exists directly in the iPhone/on my Mac, can somebody explain how to implement it/link me to a previous question? If the feature doesn't exist, can I get suggestions for 3rd party applications or websites to send texts so clients don't have their numbers shared? I've been searching for a couple hours, and nothing featuring recipient anonymity has popped up.

Thank you.

**EDIT: PLEASE READ**

Thank you for the suggestions thus far, but I am not looking for any messaging medium besides text. If the feature or application does not apply to what we consider texts received on a phone, it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Bcc (blind carbon copy) function found in all mail software, web- or app-based.

“A blind carbon copy (Bcc) of any correspondence is sent when you wish to conceal the fact that there are other recipients of the message. You might do this to discretely let somebody else in on a conversation, to send email to a list without sharing everybody's email or involvement with everybody else, or any other situation where you might desire a bit of privacy.”

From:

https://m.wikihow.com/Use-BCC-in-an-Email

Comment: Thank you, and Bcc may be a good analogue of what I am talking about. Unfortunately, I am speaking strictly about texting. Emailing will not work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I have found so far is to turn off group messaging in messages (if you have the option) and turn off imessage. All messages it seems are then sent as individual SMS to your recipients.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so please don't ask followup questions in the space available for answers. See the [FAQ] for details on how the site works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually tried this, and after comparing with recipients, it seemed like the best I could do on my device (iPhone) was have all messages sent individually according to my phone, but the recipients would receive them in groups. I could recheck the method though in case I did something incorrect.